# Left join fetch with condition fails

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, left-join, hql

I have the following `HQL` query:

```
return entityManager().createQuery(
    "SELECT page FROM ProjectPage page"
  + " left join fetch page.categorySet as category              "
  + " where page.id = :id " 
  + " and  category.parentCategory is null "
  + " and  (category.status != :status_val) " 
  ,ProjectPage.class).setParameter("id", id)
  .setParameter("status_val", 1).getSingleResult();
```

the problem is that the conditions in the where clause fails, for example, the query returns category objects whose status is 1 and category objects whose parentCategory is not null although i specified this constrains as stated above!!

Comment: Can you provide us with a SQL fiddle example? (http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @Smutje this is not SQL. It's HQL (Hibernate Query Language).

Comment: When left outer join, do NOT have conditions on the outer table in the WHERE clause, move them to the ON clause instead. (If in WHERE clause, it's no longer an OUTER JOIN, just a regular JOIN.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect this query to return `ProjectPage` object with `categorySet` filtered out based on `where` conditions, then your expectations are wrong. If `ProjectPage` instance with given id contains **any** category that pass the `where` clause conditions, it will be returned **as a whole object**. This is by design, and needed because of underlying mechanisms, caching, etc. If you need category objects that fulfill some conditions, you'll have to write a separate query for that.

Comment: sorry, would you please explain more what do you mean by a whole object? and if i want to apply the above conditions on every object of categorySet, what will i have to do ?

Comment: You'll have to query on `Category` objects, instead of `ProjectPage`. Something like `select c from Category c where <category conditions> and c.projectPage.id = :id`. The only way I know of that would do what you expect is to use [Hibernate filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html).

Comment: ok, but i still didn't understand the cause of the problem, please explain to me

Comment: what do you mean by "it will be returned as a whole object"?

Comment: For example, if you have one `PageProject` with two categories in `categorySet` - one with parent and the other without parent, and you have `where category.parentCategory is null`, you will get the whole `page` object meaning it will have both categories in its `categorySet`, not just the one with parent = null.