# Hibernate: create HQL Query with Attribute values from Sets

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to create a HQL Query that can access Attributes of a Set of spezified Objects, **let me explain via a short example**:

**Class Organization**

```
public class Organization ...{
    private int orgid;
    private Set<DomainValue> languages = new HashSet<language>(0);
    private Set<Address> adresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);
    ...
}
```

**Class Address**

```
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {
   private int addressId;
   private String city;
   private String postalCode;
   private String streetName;
   private String houseNumber;
   ...
}
```

**Language**

```
public class Orgunitlanguage  implements java.io.Serializable {
   private int orgLanguageId;
   private Orgunit orgunit;
   private Integer languageCd;
   ...
}
```

These examples are code snippets of working hibernate POJOs. So i have an organization that can have multiple addresses and languages.

I want the user to specify the search criteria, but limit them to one of each kind, so only one language, one postalcode etc.

lets say the user wants english organizations with a housenumber 22

**so i would build a hql query like this:**

```
"from organization o where o.languages.languageCd = 1 AND o.addresses.housenumber = 22"
```

Well and that dosen't work (illegal syntax) how do i access these Sets in the right way? Keep in mind i want to access a specific attribute and not just the whole object (which is really easy).

I can't seem to find a documentation that i understand so a little explaination would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to query on collections would be like this

```
from Organization o join o.languages l join o.addresses a where l.languageCd = 1 AND a.housenumber = 22
```

However, this query will return any organization that has **at least one** language with `languageCd = 1` and **at least one** address with `housenumber = 22`. It will not filter out the languages and addresses that don't fit the criteria. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940101/4074715) for a little more explanation on this.

Comment: That works fine, I'am a little disapointed thou, that hibernate dosen't offer a less database like solution for addressing Sets. Thank you very much. By the way the language is only needed for the whole organization at the moment so it works fine because for each address there is another entry with the local languages which is not displayed in the short example.

Comment: Np, glad I could help.